# Regex using Interval Matching (Exact or Range)

Tags: regex, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm trying to use the regex feature of Ms Access 2007 VBA but I'm doing something wrong.

If I have a regex of:

```
\$\d{3,5}\.\d{2}
```

The following gives me a True:  `$123.45`
And these give me False:  `$12.23`  or `$123456.45`
So all is good with this.

However, if I now test this, it gives me True !?

```
$123.456
```

Isn't the second section of my regex, ie `\d{2}`  stating that I can only have two digits after the decimal/period?
This problem also occurs even if I put a boundary, ie `\d{2,2}`

---

Sorry; figured it out.  I used the boundaries functionality.

Therefore the following now works:

```
\$\d{3,5}\.\b\d{2}\b
```

If there are any other thoughts or suggestions I'd still be more than grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
' you confirmed you don't want this ...
? RegExpTest("$123.456", "\$\d{3,5}\.\d{2}")
True
' you can add "$" to the regex pattern ...
? RegExpTest("$123.456", "\$\d{3,5}\.\d{2}$")
False

Function RegExpTest(ByVal pSource As String, _
        ByVal pPattern As String) As Boolean
    Dim re As Object ' New RegExp
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With re
        .Pattern = pPattern
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = False
    End With
    RegExpTest = re.Test(pSource)
    Set re = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: FYI, the dot was escaped in the question, but it wasn't visible because the OP didn't use code formatting.